# Windows USB Plugged In message code

Tags: c#, windows, list, message, wndproc

What is windows "USB plugged in" message code? I mean that, for example 513 is mouse left click (WM_LBUTTONDOWN) code.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363480%28v=vs.85%29.aspx DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL
0x8000

Comment: It is WM_DEVICECHANGE with a bunch of code to detect what actually happened.

Comment: Sorry, guys, but it doesn't work